# a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object in C++

Tags: c++

As exercise, I am trying a container similar to the object `std::array` with a class and I am stuck with this error (using in VSCode).

The class uses a C-style array to store the values of the `Array` object and the size of the C-style array is defined by the input `n`. This is how I define the object:

```
class Array {
    int n;
    int values[n]; // I use the C-style array
    int size{n}; // define size for member function
public:
    Array() = default;
    //     : n(0), val(0) {} // not sure how to create an empty container

    Array(int val, int n) : n(n) { // I pass an initial to fill the entire Array
        for (auto &item: values)
            item = val;
        }
    
    int get_size() const {
        return size;
    }
};
```

The line at `int values[n];` is creating the error message. I am not sure how to pass the value `n` as input: I pass it in the list initialisation at `Array(int val, int n) : n(n) {...}` but I am not sure if I have to define `n` here or somewhere else. The idea is to define an a variable using `Array arr1(3, 4);` for example.

Also, I am not sure how to create a default constructor which would make an empty array when using `Array arr2;` for example. Everything turns around on the correct `n` definition.

Additional notes:

- later, I will implement more member functions like `get_size()` which also depends on `n`
- in this exercise, I am intentionally trying to avoid template classes (which is a possible solution)
- posts similar to this question, which however I couldn’t relate:
- [member variable as default argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356984/member-variable-as-default-argument)
- [initializing default parameter with class member function/variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63406706/initializing-default-parameter-with-class-member-function-variable)

Comment: `int values[n]` is not valid in C++

Comment: You can't have array with variable length in class. How would compiler know what is the `sizeof` of this class?

Comment: This is not similar to `std::array` at all - `std::array` is a template, and, in particular, the size is a template parameter and hence known at compile time.

Comment: Thank you   Now I understand why I should use a template class instead. The compiler will know about `n` only if I create the blueprint for it: in this case decorating the class with `template<int n>`. In that case `int value[n]` will be valid. Then, declaring the Array in my original question should be changed to `Array<4> arr1(3);`.

Comment: That sounds better, yes.  Might as well template the type of the array elements while you're at it.